# Angular 9 - Local Reference, #, View child, @ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I have recently upgraded my project to angular 9.

**Issue:-**

I am facing issue with Local Reference('#') in template.

I get the value as 'undefined'.

**Objective:** 
I am trying to close mat-select on scroll.

Code:

**Html**

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="showDataForLocation($event)"
            [(value)]="dataService.startinglocation"
            (openedChange)="selectPanelOpened($event)" 
            #mySelect>

      <mat-option  aria-selected="true" [value]="location.ExLocationName" 
                  *ngFor="let location of startingPointData?.ExLocation"> 
                    {{location.ExLocationName}}
      </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**TS code**

```
@ViewChild('mySelect', { static: true }) mySelect;

@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {

    this.mySelect.close();
  }
```

The above worked perfectly on Angular 5, however now it throws error on 9.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at DetailComponent.onWindowScroll (detail.component.ts:1378)
    at DetailComponent_scroll_HostBindingHandler (detail.component.ts:77)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21593)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21635)
    at platform-browser.js:934
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:40744)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:481)
```

Comment: Try `{ static: false }` instead of `{ static: true }`.

Comment: Karmidzhanov , `{ static: false }` seems to have no effect. Getting same error.

Answer (score 6):

You should change the static flag to false.

```
// query results available in ngOnInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: true}) foo: ElementRef;

OR

// query results available in ngAfterViewInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: false}) foo: ElementRef;
```

More information on that topic the official Angular's migration guide: https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Comment: Hi, none of static method (true or false) seems to work. It shows error as `this.mySelect.close();` `Property 'close' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'`

Comment: Well at least we have some progress. Before the element was undefined, now you have something, and this something doesn't have the method you want. What I recommend is to check the official angular material doc and see if their method name has changed: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: Thanks buddy for helping me out. Sorry for late reply. There was an issue with my code, due to some condition, mat-select was not loaded in DOM, thus is was throwing error.

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
@ViewChild('mySelect', { static: true }) mySelect: matSelect;

@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {

    this.mySelect.close();
}
```

Comment: getting error as  - `Cannot find name 'matSelect'.ts(2304)`